# SUSE : How to use monitoring-plugins-disk-2.1.2-28.1.x86_64.rpm

Tags: opensuse, suse

I am first time working with SUSE . I am trying to install collectd but facing some problem , so I am trying to work with server-monitoring tools.

I have did the following steps:

1. Added repo server:monitoring
2. Downloaded monitoring-plugins-disk-2.1.2-28.1.x86_64.rpm
3. installed rpm package.

After some search I came to know check_disk is a plugin checks the amount of used disk space on a mounted file system
and generates an alert if free space is less than one of the threshold values.

**But what to do with check disk to start monitoring , how to save data in a log/csv file like collectd from check_disk at certain interval continously , how to to add notification like email.**

I have no idea how to go ahead.

Please guide me through this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used the script you are saying before, but maybe you could create a cron job in SUSE to run it and redirect the command to a log file using "command >> file.log".

Respecting to the alert, does the plugin generate the alert by itself? If it does, with a proper cron job you should have what you want.

Anyway, using any monitoring system you could be able to monitor everything and set all the alerts desired, but maybe it's too much for what you are looking for.

Comment: I have installed collectd on SUSE successfully.Thank you for your response